# min-height and position:absolute not working together?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-position

I'm making a website and defined a header tag for it. I've assigned a min-height of header and positioned it relative. But When I'm assigning `position: absolute` on its contents then the header tag is not increasing its height according to the content.

```css
header {
  background-color: aqua;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100px;
  overflow: display;
}

.firstpart,
.secondpart {
  position: absolute;
}

.firstpart {
  top: 100px;
  left: 300px;
}

.secondpart {
  top: 100px;
  right: 300px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="firstpart">
    <h1>My Name</h1>
    <h2>Student</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="secondpart">
    <h1>Welcome to my website.</h1>
    <h2>Want to give a feedback?</h2>
  </div>
</header>
```

The header maintains a 100px height and the firstpart and secondpart are showing down below it. When I remove the absolute positioning and add content one by one then header increases its height according to the content. Can anyone help?

Comment: *When I'm assigning position: absolute on its contents then the header tag is not increasing its height according to the content.* --> this is the purpose of absolute, to remove the content from the normal flow thus they will no more affect the height. Your code demonstrate this

Comment: with position absolute content will not occupy the space in the layout thus it will not force parent to take that much height. That is why on removing position absolute parent height gets increased. If you want to place contents side-by-side you can try applying display inline-block to content divs or display flex to header.

Comment: Thanks It got it.